# Leaflet controls not responding to click

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, controls

Not sure how I have managed this but my leaflet zoom controls are not clickable? They do show up on the screen but there is no mouse change when hovering over them.

Do I need to create another layer for the controls or am I missing something else from my code?

***update: The map will also not scroll or zoom in - it appears static***

This is my script relating to the map:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid');


var Jawg_Streets = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.jawg.io/jawg-streets/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?access-token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '<a href="http://jawg.io" title="Tiles Courtesy of Jawg Maps" target="_blank">&copy; <b>Jawg</b>Maps</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 22,
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    accessToken: foo
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomleft');
mymap.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Also not sure if it might relate to my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <title>Gazetteer</title>


        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">

        <!--Stylesheets-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
           integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
           crossorigin=""/>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wESLQ85D6gbsF459vf1CiZ2+rr+CsxRY0RpiF1tLlQpDnAgg6rwdsUF1+Ics2bni" crossorigin="anonymous">  
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/acad2da5ff.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="mapid" class="container-fluid"> 
        
      </div>
     
    etc

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
       crossorigin=""></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
      <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-markercluster/v1.0.0/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
      <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="application/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>


    </body> 

</html>
```

Or CSS

```
#mapid {
    height: 100vh;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine and is working for me. Maybe you disable click-events over css?

Comment: Just realised the whole map doesn't respond to dragging or zooming - it's gone completely static. I have bootstrap and  leaflet and then the only other CSS relating to the map is ```#mapid {
    height: 100vh;
   z-index: -1;
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `z-index: -1` from the css styling and it should work.

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-answer-7-7-2021?file=style.css)

[MapPanes - Leaflet Docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/)

Comment: So simple yet caused me so many problems - thank you!